# Converting from Red Hat Fuse 3.x to 7.4 - JBI

Tags: redhat, jbossfuse, fuseesb, jbi

We currently have a **JBI** app running on Red Hat Fuse ESB 3.x and intend to transition to a supported version of Fuse ESB 7.4

I am looking for some type of document or guidance on converting our JBI app... as I understand JBI packaging has been deprecated in favor of OSGI ...I am just looking for some documents that may shed some light on the process required to transition the JBI app to OSGI... I am wondering if this is a matter of using straight up Camel for what we need or if there are deeper considerations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the best practice is to refactor to Apache Camel for integration and Apache Karaf replaces the ServiceMix runtime.

1. Tons of sample code here: [Apache Karaf Examples](https://karaf.apache.org/documentation.html)
2. Specifically, a [Camel Example](https://github.com/apache/karaf/tree/master/examples/karaf-camel-example)